# How do I delete all repeating records in a table?

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause, sql-delete

I'm looking for a way to delete all repeating records in table.
I have a query, but it didn't work:

```
delete from lista
where id in
(
    select id
    from lista
    group by tytul_pl
    having count(tytul_pl) > 1
);
```

Server response:

> Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'lista' for update in
>   FROM clause

This query:

```
select id
from lista
group by tytul_pl
having count(tytul_pl) > 1
```

is working well.

Where is the error?

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: I'm using MySQL Server 5.6 CE

Comment: Did you want to keep one record and delete the repetitions or delete all records if they are repeated?

Comment: I want keep one record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want then is this

```
DELETE lista FROM lista 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
      SELECT MIN(ID) AS minID 
      FROM lista 
      GROUP BY tytul_pl) AS keepRowTable ON lista.ID = keepRowTable.minID
WHERE keepRowTable.minID IS NULL
```

You can [try it out here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ff2a3/1)

Answer (score 1):

This would work to keep one record and remove all other duplicates:

```
DELETE t1 
FROM lista t1
JOIN lista t2 
 ON t1.id > t2.id 
AND t1.tytul_pl = t2.tytul_pl
```